# How to count/sum what was selected from the code below

Tags: python

I'm doing a python activity (Codedex 15: Sorting hat). (Beginner here, Sorry)

I can't seem to figure out how can I sum up what was selected and print it as a score tally.

For short, I don't know what can I add to it to execute the way I want it to. Please help.

Below is my code:

```
#Question 1

Q1 = print("Do you like Dawn or Dusk?")
a1 = print("1) Dawn")
a2 = print("2) Dusk")
input1 = int(input("My answer is: "))

if input1 == 1:
    print("Gryffindor and Ravenclaw +1")
elif input1 == 2:
    print("Hufflepuff and Slytherin +1")
else:
    print("Wrong input")
input1 total = input1 == 1 + 0

#Question 2

Q2 = print("When I’m dead, I want people to remember me as?")
a1 = print("1) The Good")
a2 = print("2) The Great")
a3 = print("3) The Wise")
a4 = print("4) The Bold")
input2 = int(input("My answer is: "))

if input2 == 1:
    print("Hufflepuff +1")
elif input2 == 2:
    print("Slytherin +1")
elif input2 == 3:
    print("Ravenclaw +1")
elif input2 == 4:
    print("Gryffindor +1")
else:
    print("Wrong input")

#Question 3

Q3 = print("Which kind of instrument most pleases your ear?")
a1 = print("1) The Voilin")
a2 = print("2) The Trumpet")
a3 = print("3) The Piano")
a4 = print("4) The Drum")
input3 = int(input("My answer is: "))

if input3 == 1:
    print("Slytherin +1")
elif input3 == 2:
    print("Hufflepuff +1")
elif input3 == 3:
    print("Ravenclaw +1")
elif input3 == 4:
    print("Gryffindor +1")
else:
    print("Wrong input")

#Total
total = input1 + input2 +input3
print("Gryffindor", total)
print("Slytherin", total)
print("Hufflepuff", total)
print("Ravenclaw", total)


Already tried possible solution based on the curriculum/guide that I am following and also looked into the web but can't find the code that I need.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain your totals in a dictionary keyed on house names.

**Always** validate input especially when you're expecting numeric data.

Do not repeat strings. Better to set up a global variable as a constant (there's no such thing as a constant in Python but you can manage this conventionally such as by using uppercase variable names)

```
GRYFFINDOR = 'Gryffindor'
RAVENCLAW = 'Ravenclaw'
HUFFLEPUFF = 'Hufflepuff'
SLYTHERIN = 'Slytherin'

houses = {
    GRYFFINDOR: 0,
    RAVENCLAW: 0,
    HUFFLEPUFF: 0,
    SLYTHERIN: 0
}

def get_input(prompt, vals):
    while True:
        try:
            if (r := int(input(f'{prompt}: '))) in vals:
                return r
            raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print('Wrong input.')

if get_input('Q1) Do you like Dawn or Dusk?\n\t1) Dawn\n\t2) Dusk\n', {1, 2}) == 1:
    houses[GRYFFINDOR] += 1
    houses[RAVENCLAW] += 1
else:
    houses[HUFFLEPUFF] += 1
    houses[SLYTHERIN] += 1

r = get_input('Q2) When I\'m dead, I want people to remember me as:\n\t1) The Good\n\t2) The Great\n\t3) The Wise\n\t4) The Bold\n', {1,2,3,4})

house = [HUFFLEPUFF, SLYTHERIN, RAVENCLAW, GRYFFINDOR][r-1]
houses[house] += 1

r = get_input('Q3) Which kind of instrument most pleases your ear?\n\t1) The violin\n\t2) The trumpet\n\t3) The piano\n\t4) The drum\n', {1,2,3,4})

house = [SLYTHERIN, HUFFLEPUFF, RAVENCLAW, GRYFFINDOR][r-1]
houses[house] += 1

print(max(houses.items(), key=lambda e: e[1])[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most basic way to do this is to assign a total variable to each house and to add/subtract to that value whenever there is a change in the house points. The following code has separate total variables to store the total of each house and print them out in the end. This should fix your problem in the most basic manner possible which I believe is sufficient for your case.

```py
Gryffindor_total = 0
Ravenclaw_total = 0
Hufflepuff_total = 0
Slytherin_total = 0

#Question 1

Q1 = print("Do you like Dawn or Dusk?")
a1 = print("1) Dawn")
a2 = print("2) Dusk")
input1 = int(input("My answer is: "))

if input1 == 1:
    print("Gryffindor and Ravenclaw +1")
    Gryffindor_total += 1
    Ravenclaw_total += 1
elif input1 == 2:
    print("Hufflepuff and Slytherin +1")
    Hufflepuff_total += 1
    Slytherin_total += 1
else:
    print("Wrong input")

#Question 2

Q2 = print("When I’m dead, I want people to remember me as?")
a1 = print("1) The Good")
a2 = print("2) The Great")
a3 = print("3) The Wise")
a4 = print("4) The Bold")
input2 = int(input("My answer is: "))

if input2 == 1:
    print("Hufflepuff +1")
    Hufflepuff_total += 1
elif input2 == 2:
    print("Slytherin +1")
    Slytherin_total += 1
elif input2 == 3:
    print("Ravenclaw +1")
    Ravenclaw_total += 1
elif input2 == 4:
    print("Gryffindor +1")
    Gryffindor_total += 1
else:
    print("Wrong input")

#Question 3

Q3 = print("Which kind of instrument most pleases your ear?")
a1 = print("1) The Voilin")
a2 = print("2) The Trumpet")
a3 = print("3) The Piano")
a4 = print("4) The Drum")
input3 = int(input("My answer is: "))

if input3 == 1:
    print("Slytherin +1")
    Slytherin_total += 1
elif input3 == 2:
    print("Hufflepuff +1")
    Hufflepuff_total += 1
elif input3 == 3:
    print("Ravenclaw +1")
    Ravenclaw_total += 1
elif input3 == 4:
    print("Gryffindor +1")
    Gryffindor_total += 1
else:
    print("Wrong input")

#Total
print("Gryffindor", Gryffindor_total)
print("Slytherin", Slytherin_total)
print("Hufflepuff", Hufflepuff_total)
print("Ravenclaw", Ravenclaw_total)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need 4 different totals for each faculty. Something like this:

```
#Initialization of totals

slytherin, gryffindor, ravenclaw, hufflepuff = 0,0,0,0

#Question 1

Q1 = print("Do you like Dawn or Dusk?")
a1 = print("1) Dawn")
a2 = print("2) Dusk")
input1 = int(input("My answer is: "))

if input1 == 1:
    print("Gryffindor and Ravenclaw +1")
    gryffindor += 1
    ravenclaw += 1
elif input1 == 2:
    print("Hufflepuff and Slytherin +1")
    hufflepuff += 1
    slytherin += 1    
else:
    print("Wrong input")

# Other questions

#Total
print("Gryffindor: ", gryffindor)
print("Slytherin: ", slytherin)
print("Hufflepuff: ", hufflepuff)
print("Ravenclaw: ", ravenclaw)
```